OSError: [Errno 30] Read-only file system: 'tmp/<filename>'
I have a lambda function that leverages a library that wraps an API and manages authentication sessions. To manage the session, the library expects a file containing credentials and a session token to exist. If the token contained in the file is expired, the library will fetch another one using said credentials and write the new session token to the file.
However, the library's attempt to write to the file is causing my lambda to fail with OSError: [Errno 30] Read-only file system: 'tmp/oauth2.json', despite the file it is attempting to write to being in the /tmp directory. My lambda's file structure can be seen below. Is there any possible way I can work around this? I'm hoping that I just have a misunderstanding of where the authentication file should live.
If it is of any help, the library I'm using is yahoo_oauth, and the failure occurs when this code is executed:
from yahoo_oauth import OAuth2
oauth = OAuth2(None, None, from_file='tmp/oauth2.json')



What if you add a / to the path?  What you have is not using /tmp.

@stdunbar In that case, the library fails to find the file: `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/oauth2.json'

"despite the file it is attempting to write to being in the /tmp directory" No it's not, it's in the tmp directory that is inside your Lambda function deployment, relative to your handler function. That is actually going to be something like /var/task/src/tmp at runtime. You only have read access to that folder. That library is apparently trying to write an auth.json file to the same folder that the oauth2.json file is in. You need to look if you can change that behavior.

@MarkB I pasted the error wrong. I updated the post, it's trying to write to tmp/oauth2.json, sorry about that. Is there a way I can add my json file to the /tmp directory in AWS that my lambda can read from and write to?

You would have to have your code first copy that file to /tmp somehow, before initializing the OAuth2 library.

@MarkB Makes sense, but apparently, the /tmp directory I've been trying to read and write to isn't the correct one. As you mentioned, it's something like /var/task/src/tmp. If that's the case, how can I write to the /tmp directory I'm actually interested in?

How about you extract a [mcve] to rule out that it's not something entirely different?

You can write to the /tmp directly by including a / character at the beginning of the directory. The tmp directory you are trying to read/write to is a relative directory, not the system's /tmp directory. Each character in a path is important. You can't leave out / characters and expect things to work the same. I suggest researching the difference between "relative" and "absolute" paths.

you get FileNotFoundError when specifying /tmp/oauth2.json, it suggests that the file doesn’t exist yet in the /tmp directory. AWS Lambda initializes /tmp as an empty. Therefore, the library  cannot locate the needed file.
you can try to copy the file to your specific directory beforehand:
import shutil
import os
from yahoo_oauth import OAuth2

# Define source and destination paths
source_path = 'tmp/oauth2.json'  # current path
destination_path = '/tmp/oauth2.json' # desired path

if not os.path.exists(destination_path):
    shutil.copyfile(source_path, destination_path)

# Now initialize the OAuth2 object
oauth = OAuth2(None, None, from_file=destination_path)

